# Android Studio & Gradle: Adding external classes to build path

Tags: gradle, android-studio, .class-file

I have two .class files that I want to include in my build path. Eclipse does this automagically just by putting them on my libs folder, but I can't get it to work in Android Studio. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Most projects created in Android Studio have a bit of build script that will automatically pick up any **.jar** files you put in the **libs** directory of a module. However, this only finds **.jar** files, not **.class** files. To get it to work, you can bundle those classes into a **.jar** and put that in the directory. Look at the manual page for Java's `jar` command-line tool to figure out how to make it work.